# Shape on hover in <tr>

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

I am trying to add some shape on the left part of my table (tr) on hover.
Something like that:

[image]

Here's my CSS for that:

```
table tr:hover:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    width: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    background-color: #23a298;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Now, my table just moving wildly and there's no shape. Where's problem ?
More code: https://jsfiddle.net/yw8tp5kL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used  `table {white-space: nowrap;}`

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
}

button
{
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #23a298;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height:25px;
}

#content button:focus {outline:0;}

#content button:hover
{

 background-color: #22dccd;
  -webkit-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: r 0.4s ease-out;
  transition:  0.4s ease-out;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

table {
  width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

tr:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
 heightv: 60px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 background-color: #f4fafa;
  line-height:65px;
}

tr:first-of-type a{
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight:600;
}

tr:first-of-type:hover {
    background-color: #f4fafa;
}

tr a:hover {
  color: #23a298;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  transition:  0.4s ease-out;
}

table tr td:first-child:hover {

  border-left:3px solid #23a298
}

table tr.border td {
  border-bottom: 2pt solid #f6f7fb;
}

table td {
  color: #222222;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

table tr:hover {
  background-color: #f9fcfc;
}

table tr:hover:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    width: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    background-color: #23a298;
    top: 0px;
}

table td:first-child {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #23a298;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table style="width: 100%">
              <colgroup>
                 <col span="1" style="width: 23%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 22%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 10%;">
              </colgroup>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="border">
                  <th><a href="#">Name &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">Person &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">Last updated &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">Date &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">Learning objects &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">More</a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">Das Ist Deutch KOMPAKT 7</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;admin@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>138</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">201-2</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;apiecuch@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">All Clear</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;mjakubek@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>212</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">All Audioteka</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;admin@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>156</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">Brainy</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;apiecuch@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>125</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">Bugs Team 1</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;mjakubek@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>136</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">FNAIM</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;admin@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>25</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">Hello Explorer</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;apiecuch@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>75</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">ICC 101</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;mjakubek@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>83</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">ICC 101-12</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;admin@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>256</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.border:hover th:first-child` hover change th td add border.

https://jsfiddle.net/yw8tp5kL/3/

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are using the `::before` pseudo-element to add content before a table row, which essentially will break the table layout and lead to unpredictable results.

So, I modified your code and added the psuedo-element to first cell of the row when you hover over it. Also I added relative and absolute positioning to position the border perfectly on left most corner of the first cell.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

button
{
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #23a298;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content button:focus {outline:0;}

#content button:hover
{

 background-color: #22dccd;
  -webkit-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: r 0.4s ease-out;
  transition:  0.4s ease-out;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
 heightv: 60px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 background-color: #f4fafa;
  line-height:65px;
}

tr:first-of-type a{
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight:600;
}

tr:first-of-type:hover {
    background-color: #f4fafa;
}

tr a:hover {
  color: #23a298;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition:  0.4s ease-out;
  transition:  0.4s ease-out;
}

table tr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height:65px;
}

table tr.border td {
  border-bottom: 2pt solid #f6f7fb;
}

table td {
  color: #222222;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

table tr:hover {
  background-color: #f9fcfc;
}

table tr:hover>td:first-child:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    background-color: #23a298;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}

table td:first-child {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #23a298;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
              <colgroup>
                 <col span="1" style="width: 23%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 22%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
                 <col span="1" style="width: 10%;">
              </colgroup>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="border">
                  <th><a href="#">Name &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">Person &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">Last updated &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">Date &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">Learning objects &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                  <th><a href="#">More</a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">Das Ist Deutch KOMPAKT 7</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;admin@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>138</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">201-2</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;apiecuch@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">All Clear</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;mjakubek@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>212</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">All Audioteka</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;admin@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>156</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">Brainy</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;apiecuch@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>125</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">Bugs Team 1</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;mjakubek@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>136</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">FNAIM</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;admin@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>25</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">Hello Explorer</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;apiecuch@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>75</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">ICC 101</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;mjakubek@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>83</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                  <td><a href="#">ICC 101-12</a></td>
                  <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;admin@n-educatio.com</a></td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>2016/05/09 10:56</td>
                  <td>256</td>
                  <td><button class="ver2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this updated code here: https://jsfiddle.net/yw8tp5kL/4/
Following are the code changes you need to do:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

table tr:hover {
  background-color: #f9fcfc;
  border-left:4px solid lightgreen;
}
```